# WPF ignore clicks outside of popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

In my WPF app I want to show a popup when I click a button.

If I click outside the popup, I want the popup to be closed. I can accomplish this by setting `StaysOpen=False` on the popup.

But when I click outside the popup, I want WPF to ignore the initial click that closes the popup. For example, if I click outside the popup on another button, I don't want that button to execute the click method.

How can I make WPF ignore the click outside the popup while it's open?

Here is some sample code. The popup opens when I click the "Popup" button, and it closes when I click outside. But I can click the "PrintMessage" button while the popup is open and its click event will fire. I would like its click event not to fire.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Popup x:Key="pop" StaysOpen="False" Placement="MousePoint">
            <UniformGrid Background="Red">
                <Button>Btn1</Button>
                <Button>Btn2</Button>
            </UniformGrid>
        </Popup>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid>
        <Button Click="Popup_Click">Popup</Button>
        <Button Click="PrintMessage_Click">PrintMessage</Button>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Popup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup pop = (Popup)Resources["pop"];
        pop.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void PrintMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Test");
    }
}
```